# iOS App crashes since Xamarin.Forms version 2.3.4 when distributed via TestFlight

Tags: xamarin.ios, crash, xamarin.forms, testflight

We have a Xamarin.Forms app for iOS and Android that we have in the stores for some months now. We develop with VS 2017. For testing the iOS-version, we use TestFlight.

Everything worked pretty well, until mid-april when we wanted to test a new release via TestFlight:
We installed the iOS-App on our test devices via TestFlight, and now on our test devices the app closes down right after the splash screen without generating a crash report (we use HockeyApp).

The app works fine though on the iOS-simulator and when being published directly on a device (iPad) via VS.

We found out that the problem is the update of Xamarin.Forms from version 2.3.3.180 to version 2.3.4.231 or later.

We would like to use latest version of Xamarin.Forms. Does anyone have the same issue and did you find a solution?

Comment: Is there any info in the HockeyApp reports?

Comment: Unfortunately we do not get any entry for this crash in HockeyApp.

Comment: There is a option for that to send startup crashes, otherwise hook up your device to Xcode and check the logs yourself to see if anything is in there

Comment: I can't find the option in HockeyApp to send startup crashes. Apparently this is not possible any more for Xamarin.iOS? I'm not in the office today, so I will hook up the device on Friday.

Comment: Same problem I am facing, did you got any solution?

Comment: I went back to Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3 for the moment and haven't had time to investigate further yet. I hope to have some time for this next week. Please let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 0):

We just found the solution for this problem:

We use a custom font for our app and changed the font of the navigation bar in the AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching method by using UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes.

This caused the iOS version of our app to crash when distributing via TestFlight. We removed the code to change the font and now we can publish the app again.